# firebreath plugin could not be loaded on mac os 10.7

Tags: c++, macos, google-chrome, openssl, firebreath

### Question

I have got a browser plugin created from firebreath worked fine on mac osx 10.8. But I got an "could not load UploaderPlugin(the name of my plugin)" error from Chrome on mac osx 10.7.

Several external libraries are included in my plugin project. After several hours of work I found that when I removed the libcurl library from my project the error went away, and the same error appears each time I try to include the libcurl library.

So it is quite clear that the error has something to do with the libcurl library. Since libcurl relies on openssl and zlib. I compiled the three libraries from source code again but the same error remains unresolved.

### error message from the console

> 13-10-10 下午12:56:33.500 Google Chrome Helper EH: Error loading /Users/admin/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/npUploaderPlugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/npUploaderPlugin:  dlopen(/Users/admin/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/npUploaderPlugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/npUploaderPlugin, 262): Symbol not found: _CAST_ecb_encrypt
>     Referenced from: /Users/admin/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/npUploaderPlugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/npUploaderPlugin
>     Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
>    in /Users/admin/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/npUploaderPlugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/npUploaderPlugin
>
> 13-10-10 下午12:56:33.501 [0x0-0x2a82a8].com.google.Chrome: [10071:2819:1010/125633:ERROR:webplugin_delegate_proxy.cc(390)] PluginMsg_Init returned false
>
> 13-10-10 下午12:56:33.501 [0x0-0x2a82a8].com.google.Chrome: [10071:2819:1010/125633:ERROR:webplugin_impl.cc(258)] Couldn't initialize plug-in

---

Deciding from the error msg I can see that the main problem is that the symbol _CAST_ecb_encrypt could not be found. I googled it and got nothing concerned.

### envrionment

mac os x 10.8 + chrome 28.0.1500.71        (works fine)

mac os x 10.7 + chrome 29.0.1547.22 beta   (got the error msg)

firebreath version: 1.7

libcurl    version: 7.26.0

openssl    version: 1.0.1c

zlib       version: 1.2.7

c-ares     version: 1.10.0

Any kind of advice would be appreciated. And plz do not hesitate to inform me if you need more detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

It actually may or may not be directly related to libcurl; it could be something that curl is causing to be linked in because of how you're linking it. My first guess would be that you need to set your deployment target to 10.7; if you build on 10.8, by default the target and SDK you will use are the 10.8 target and 10.8 sdk.  *usually* you can safely use the 10.8 sdk to build for 10.7, but you may need to set the deployment target.

You can do that by adding `-D CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.8` to your [prep script](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/Prep+Scripts#PrepScripts-Macparams):

```
../firebreath/prepmac.sh ./projectDir ./buildDir -D CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.8
```

Comment: In fact, I have tried it to set the deployment target to 10.7 but the error remains the same.

Comment: I would try building it on a 10.7 box, then, and see if it makes a difference; you could also try building using the 10.7 SDK; Another thing to try would be linking in the CommonCrypto framework, since that's where the symbol referenced lives